# no permission to get event infos with facebook api since today

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook API, I load the events I attend with this query:
/EVENT-ID?fields=ticket_uri,cover,place,name,description,start_time,event_times,updated_time

This has been working well for a long time, but since today I'm getting:
"Object with ID 'EVENT-ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."
I can't find any information about recent changes to this topic in the API.

Does anyone have information on why it's broken today?

I tried it also with the Graph API Explorer and got the info with no permission. My Facebook is in dev mode

Update Info:
For old events, created by myself, i don't have a permission.
For old events, created by pages, where i am admin, i have the permission to read the event details.

Comment: Is this for any event id (that used to work previously), or just a particular one?

Comment: in the last months i got this error maybe on 5% of the event ids. Since today i have the error on 100%

Comment: Can you still access the event directly on Facebook?

Comment: Yes, only for example: https://www.facebook.com/events/861378175352334/

The Facebook API generally work, when if use for example: /me

Comment: Really hard to say, to what extend this _should_ still work. Especially regarding events, Facebook's documentation is rather lacking clarity in a lot of places. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ says right on top, _"Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners."_

Comment: Yes, this i also read. But till yesterday it works for years for me as private user.

I think this means, if you want all events from a special user or a page (/USER-ID/events). This works in the past, but not since maybe 4 or 5 years